# How to delete partitions?

Tags: partitioning

I have a Toshiba laptop satellite with a 300GB hard drive and it is partitioned into six partitions and I want to cut/trim them to just dual-boot Windows 7 and Ubuntu 14.04, which is a reinstall so it /`sda8`. I had 13.10 which `/sda6` and I also have 14.10 `/sda7` all are `ext4`'s and was able to reformat the partition `6` but I can't delete the partition and I keep getting:

```
CAN'T DELETE AS LONG AS A PARTION GRATER 6 IS MOUNTED
```

And I cant unmount `/sda8` still, that what is running, also how would I get these other partitions removed after? Can I combine the old into one and change `/sda8` to `6` so it will automaticaly load? I want to keep Windows 7 at present.

Comment: Boot from LiveUSB and you will be able to do anything you like.

Answer (score 1):

You should boot into live mode from a LiveUSB and use the provided disks utility to unmount the partitions /sda6 and above, then you will be able to remove the unneeded partitons and create partitions for 14.04.